# Too many data on socket using epoll edge trigger

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

The scenario is like this: one process is using epoll on several sockets, all sockets are set non-blocking and edge triggered; then EPOLLIN event occurs on one socket, then we start to read data on its fd, but the problem is that there are too many data coming in, and in the while loop reading data, the return value of `recv` is always larger than 0. So the application is stuck there, reading data and cannot move on.

Any idea how should I deal with this?

```
constexpr int max_events = 10;
constexpr int buf_len = 8192;
....

epoll_event events[max_events];
char buf[buf_len];
int n;
auto fd_num = epoll_wait(...);
for(auto i = 0; i < fd_num; i++) {
    if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
        for(;;) {
            n = ::read(events[i].data.fd, buf, sizeof(buf));
            if (errno == EAGAIN)
                break;
            if (n <= 0)
            {
                on_disconnect_(events[i].data.fd);
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                on_data_(events[i].data.fd, buf, n);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of data do you receive? in general you can/should work with already received data while reading more from socket. preferably in parallel.

Comment: What's in the `...`? It's not sufficient to post pseudocode here.

Comment: This is why I prefer level-triggered epoll, with a single, bounded read each time. Sure my event loop has to tick over a few more times on average, but the duration of each is way more consistent so the rest of my app doesn't ever starve.

Comment: @wtom yes, that is correct, but as there are multiple sockets being registered in epoll, other sockets' event cannot be processed without finishing the current one, this is the main concern

Comment: @EJP you are right, I will make it more complete later

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I will try LT tmr and see if it can handle this thanks

Comment: @Chitanda: I wasn't necessarily suggesting that you switch to it. I don't know nearly enough about your application to do so.

Comment: As your actual code bears no resemblance to what you originally posted I am deleting my answer. I do not appreciRe having my time wasted in this manner.

Comment: @EJP sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using edge triggered mode the data must be read in one `recv` call, otherwise it risks starving other sockets. This issue has been written about in numerous blogs, e.g. [Epoll is fundamentally broken](https://idea.popcount.org/2017-02-20-epoll-is-fundamentally-broken-12/).

Make sure that your user-space receive buffer is at least the same size as the kernel receive socket buffer. This way you read the entire kernel buffer in one `recv` call.

Also, you can process ready sockets in a round-robin fashion, so that the control flow does not get stuck in `recv` loop for one socket. That works best with the user-space receive buffer being of the same size as the kernel one. E.g.:

```
auto n = epoll_wait(...);
for(int dry = 0; dry < n;) {
    for(auto i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(events[i].events & EPOLLIN) {
            // Do only one read call for each ready socket
            // before moving to the next ready socket.
            auto r = recv(...);
            if(-1 == r) {
                if(EAGAIN == errno) {
                    events[i].events ^= EPOLLIN;
                    ++dry;
                }
                else
                    ; // Handle error.
            }
            else if(!r){
                // Process client disconnect.
            }
            else {
                // Process data received so far.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This version can be further improved to avoid scanning the entire `events` array on each iteration.

---

In you original post `do {} while(n > 0);` is incorrect and it leads to an endless loop. I assume it is a typo.

Comment: I am doing what is mention in the `man epoll` page, read until getting a EAGAIN return, but I never get that...

Comment: @EJP `select` operates in level-triggered mode only, it is not relevant here. It is hard to makes sense of your comment.

Comment: @EJP `poll` also does not operate in edge-triggered mode. Read up on what edge-triggered is http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html

Comment: @EJP It solves the problem by not having to call `recv` on the same socket multiple times in a loop. That loop can be endless when more data arrives on the socket between successive `recv` calls, which is the issue observed by the OP.

Comment: In other words you still haven't spotted the variable scope problem.

Comment: @EJP That `while(n > 0);` is a typo, I suppose. Because edge-triggered starvation is a common issue.

Comment: I have give up epoll in the end, as my app does not require multi-threading. I choose to loop through all sockets myself and do recv for each one. This seems to be in accordance with your answer, as if there is infinite data comes in some socket, then round robin with continue without exit.

Comment: @Chitanda I would probably just use level-triggered `epoll` and equal user/kernel buffer size.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin thanks I will also have a try for this!